# Recently i upgraded my hosting to cloud and my Post urls are not working anymore, my permalink setting is as below

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

[Permalink setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS2Qm.png)

However urls with https://sitename.com//%category%/  are working fine
all urls having postname not working

I have already changed and restore permalink settings, done cache flushing

I need help to understand this issue, i have not recently installed any new plugin however i have changed my theme from colormag to OcenaWP

Answer (score 0):

First check if switching back to the colormag will fix the issue, if not, try to remove the last "/".